# error in installing .net framework 3.5 on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, .net-3.5

When I checked Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 under Windows features and clicked OK to install it, I got this error message:

> An error has occurred. Not all of the features were successfully changed.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you download the .NET 3.5 Redistributable Package and try to install that one?

Comment: I downloaded this but in installing give error.

Comment: .NET 3.5 should be [preinstalled on Se7en](http://johnhaller.com/jh/useful_stuff/dotnet_portable_apps/).

Comment: 3.5 isn't the same as 3.5.1 though

Comment: Install net framework 4.0 instead.

Comment: @MJH: And which one?

Comment: I installed net framework 4.0,but some software only work by .net framework 3.5.1

Comment: 4.x also includes 3.x and 2.x versions.

Comment: @harrymc: You sure about that? I don't think so. It supports old programs, but it's a completely new framework, with a new version of every assembly.

Comment: Check the "Application" and "System" Event Logs for messages, then post them here.

Comment: Download and run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), then find events that weren't successful to try to narrow things down. Best of luck though, if you haven't used it before.

Comment: @Lambert: From [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx) : "Framework 4 is backward-compatible with applications that were built with the .NET Framework versions 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5".

Comment: @harrymc: Like I said, "it supports old programs", but it doesn't *include* those frameworks in the same way .NET 3.5 includes .NET 2.0. In fact, they released breaking changes in 4.0, and it's not 100% compatible with all previous programs--I had a program that broke after the migration. So no, .NET 4.0 doesn't include the older versions any more than Windows 7 "includes" XP.

Comment: @Lambert: If you had a case of a 3.5 program that broke under 4.0, you should report it to Microsoft.

Comment: @harrymmc: I would do that, except that the behavior was completely documented: I remember it said something about a permission change in .NET 4.0 that was intentional (I *think* it had to do with reflection, but I'm not sure); it wasn't a bug, so there's not much to report.

Answer (score 1):

When you turned the feature on did you just check the root node and leave the other two sub nodes for WCF un-checked?

The WCF HTTP Activation is used with IIS and IIS should automatically be turned on when you enable this feature but if there was an issue turning IIS on then the error you are seeing may be related to IIS and not .net 3.5.1.

Comment: If you are going to leave a -1 then you should at least leave a comment. The point of this is to provide useful feedback to build up an intellectual wealth of information to not only help the OP but anyone else in the same situation.

Comment: It's probably because you didn't use the edit feature

Comment: @Bronumski: I only checked MS .Net Framework without sub node.

Comment: @random My previous answer was irrelevant and completely wrong so the comments would have distracted from the changes to the answer.

Comment: @MJH: Did you try turning the feature off and then back on again?

Comment: @Bronumski: Yes.

Comment: @MJH was there anything logged in the Application or System logs?

Comment: @Bronumski: How can access to Application or System logs?

Comment: @MJH Right click "Computer" in the start menu and select "Manage". Expand "Event Logs" then "Windows Logs"

Comment: Fault bucket 1450460186, type 5
Event Name: CbsPackageServicingFailure2
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: 6.1.7601.17105
P2: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package
P3: 6.1.7600.16385
P4: amd64
P5: unknown
P6: 80070643
P7: Execute
P8: Installed
P9: Installed
P10: Windows Optional Component Manager

Comment: Attached files:
C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20101002204134.cab
C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20101027151828.cab
C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20101123211700.cab
C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20101216140936.cab
C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20110103203457.cab
C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log
C:\Windows\servicing\Sessions\Sessions.xml
C:\Windows\winsxs\poqexec.log
C:\Windows\inf\setupapi.dev.log

Comment: @MJH I'm sorry but I don't think I can assist any further. Have a try on one of the microsoft forums